# Using Python and Beautifulsoup how do I select the desired table in a div?

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I would like to be able to select the table containing the "Accounts Payable" text but I'm not getting anywhere with what I'm trying and I'm pretty much guessing using findall.  Can someone show me how I would do this?

For example this is what I start with:

```
<div>
<tr>
<td class="lft lm">Accounts Payable
</td>
<td class="r">222.82</td>
<td class="r">92.54</td>
<td class="r">100.34</td>
<td class="r rm">99.95</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="lft lm">Accrued Expenses
</td>
<td class="r">36.49</td>
<td class="r">33.39</td>
<td class="r">31.39</td>
<td class="r rm">36.47</td>
</tr>
</div>
```

And this is what I would like to get as a result:

```
<tr>
<td class="lft lm">Accounts Payable
</td>
<td class="r">222.82</td>
<td class="r">92.54</td>
<td class="r">100.34</td>
<td class="r rm">99.95</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Let me know if there is any specific questions about my solution to your question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can select the *td* elements with class *lft lm* and then examine the element.string to determine if you have the "Accounts Payable" td:

```
import sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

# where so_soup.txt is your html
f = open ("so_soup.txt", "r")
data = f.readlines ()
f.close ()

soup = BeautifulSoup ("".join (data))

cells = soup.findAll('td', {"class" : "lft lm"})
for cell in cells:
    # You can compare cell.string against "Accounts Payable" 
    print (cell.string)
```

If you would like to examine the following siblings for *Accounts Payable* for instance, you could use the following:

```
if (cell.string.strip () == "Accounts Payable"):
    sibling = cell.findNextSibling ()
    while (sibling):
        print ("\t" + sibling.string)
        sibling = sibling.findNextSibling ()
```

**Update for Edit**

If you would like to print out the original HTML, just for the siblings that follow the *Accounts Payable* element, this is the code for that:

```
lines = ["<tr>"]
for cell in cells:
    lines.append (cell.prettify().decode('ascii'))
    if (cell.string.strip () == "Accounts Payable"):
        sibling = cell.findNextSibling ()
        while (sibling):
            lines.append (sibling.prettify().decode('ascii'))
            sibling = sibling.findNextSibling ()
lines.append ("</tr>")

f = open ("so_soup_out.txt", "wt")
f.writelines (lines)
f.close ()
```